# Tratando a lógica e exeções - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Eu tenho alguns botões do qual no `onclick` dos mesmos trabalham com duas requisições Ajax para um arquivo externo que adicionam produtos, mas isso não é de extrema importância nessa questão. O meu problema é o seguinte: se o botão comprar for clicado, o produto é adicionado, porém se a página for atualizada o mesmo estará lá, mas eu só posso ter um produto do mesmo de cada vez e se depois da página atualizada o botão comprar for clicado novamente, outro produto é adicionado e isso não pode acontecer, pois o que já estiver adicionado deve ser retirado a partir da função `removeCartaotoCart` para que o novo seja adicionado, para que eu tenha somente um produto por vez.

**Código dos botões:**

```
 <button type="button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="addCartao('<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>')" name="cartaoMensagem<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" id="cartaoMensagem<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"><span><span>Comprar</span></span></button>
 <button style="display: none;" type="button" id="cartaoMensagemRemover<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" title="Remover" class="button btn-cart" onclick="removeCartaotoCart('<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>')" name="cartaoMensagem<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"><span><span>Remover</span></span></button>
```

**Código das requisições Ajax:**

```
var productSelected = "";
            function addCartao(product_id){
                if( productSelected != "" ){
                    removeCartaotoCart(productSelected);    // Remove the item in cart, if there is one.
                  }
                $j('#cartaoMensagem'+product_id).hide();
                $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product_id).show();
                $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product_id).css({'background-color': '#000000'});
                $j.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "adiciona.php",
                  data: {
                    product_id: product_id
                  },
                  dataType: 'json',
                  cache : false,
                  beforeSend: function () {

                  },
                  success: function (retorno) {
                    var button = $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product_id);
                    productSelected = product_id;  
                    $j('.item-custom').append('<tr id="trAppend'+product_id+'"><td class="a-center lc-thumbnails"><img src="' + retorno['imagem'] + '" width="50" height="50" alt="' + retorno['name'] + '"></td><td><h3 class="product-name">' + retorno['name'] + '</h3></td><td class="a-center">1</td><td class="a-right"><span class="cart-price"><span class="price"> R$ ' + retorno['price'] + '</span></span></td></tr>');
                    getSubTotal();
                    getGrandTotal();
                  },
                  complete: function () {

                  },
                  error: function (x,y,z) {
                    alert("error");
                    alert(x);
                    alert(y);
                    alert(z);
                    window.location.reload();
                    history.go(0);
                    window.location.href=window.location.href;
                  }
              });
            }

            function removeCartaotoCart(itemId){
                productSelected = ""; 
                $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+itemId).hide();
                $j('#cartaoMensagem'+itemId).show();
                $j.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"remove.php",
                    data:{
                        itemId: itemId
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function(){

                    },
                    success: function(retorno){
                        var button = $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+itemId);
                        $j('.item-custom #trAppend'+itemId+'').remove();
                        getSubTotal();
                        getGrandTotal();

                    },
                    complete: function () {

                    },
                    error: function (x,y,z) {
                    alert("error");
                    alert(x);
                    alert(y);
                    alert(z);
                    window.location.reload();
                    history.go(0);
                    window.location.href=window.location.href;
                  }
                });
            }
```

**Observação: A partir da variável `productSelected`, eu consigo tratar uma exceção: se o botão comprar for clicado e já houver um produto adicionado, o mesmo é removido para o novo ser adicionado, porém essa outra exceção com relação a atualizar a página não sei como devo prosseguir para soluciona-lá. Acho que o correto a se fazer é na atualização da página ele remover o produto que foi adicionado segundo o botão comprar, a partir do seu id.**

Comment: Você gastou 80% do seu texto para descrever uma situação sem relevância pro problema. E o problema está mal explicado. Por favor, seja sucinto e claro.

Comment: @BrunnoVianna eu atualizei a questão, agora sendo mais claro e explicando mais o problema.

Comment: Por que vc precisa dar um reload na página?? Já que está usando Ajax, não seria mais fácil remover o botão "comprar" e o item relacionado a ele com jQuery `.remove()`?

Comment: @Dvdsamm Sim, ou na atualização da página, o item clicado vir com o botão remover ativo, não o comprar, que seria o que eu precisaria no caso.

Comment: Então, se vc apagar os reloads do código não funciona?

Comment: @Dvdsamm Funciona, porém eu queria que tipo, o botão comprar foi clicado, em seguida ele é "trocado" pelo remover. Se a página é atualizada, ele vem como comprar novamente, mas eu precisaria que nesse caso ele viesse como remover.

Comment: Agora entendi. O caso é o seguinte: quando a pessoa clica em comprar, vc precisa guardar essa informação em algum lugar, para quando a página for carregada novamente, puxar essa informação e fazer a comparação. Não sei como vc está fazendo essa "guarda" de informação. Se for no banco, vc deve puxar isso do banco e ver se o item que foi "comprado" está lá, e, se estiver, vc exibir o botão "remover"  em vez do "comprar".

Comment: @Dvdsamm Isso, seria isso mesmo que você disse, porém estou tento dificuldades em "guardar" essa informação, pois não sei como devo prosseguir para fazer o mesmo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65603/discussion-between-dvdsamm-and-matheus-portela).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução da qual achei muito tempo depois foi no carregamento da página é feita uma requisição `ajax` para poder verificar se há produto adicionado e o valor do retorno da requisição é adicionado em dois `input` do tipo `hidden`, para pegar esse valor e fazer a requisição que remove o produto.

**Código dos `input's`:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="cartao_adicionado" id="cartao_adicionado" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="cartao_adicionado_product_id" id="cartao_adicionado_product_id" value="0" />
```

**Código da requisição `Ajax`:**

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
        //Requisição Ajax para ver se existe produtos na atualização da página
        $j.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "verifica.php",
            data:{

            },
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){
            },
            success: function(retorno){
                $j('#cartao_adicionado').attr('value', retorno['adicionado']) ;
                $j('#cartao_adicionado_product_id').attr('value', retorno['id_produto']);
                isCartaoAdicionado = $j('#cartao_adicionado').val();
                isCartaoAdicionadoProductId = $j('#cartao_adicionado_product_id').val();
                removeCartaotoCart(isCartaoAdicionadoProductId); //chama a requisição para remove o produto a partir do seu id.
            },
            complete: function(){

            },
            error: function(x,y,z){
                alert(x);
                alert(y);
                alert(z);
                alert("Erro!");
                window.location.reload();
                history.go(0);
                window.location.href = "{{store url=''}}";
            }
        });
    })
```